# ASP.NET C# object in Master Page to be visible to all other pages that are based on that Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, master-pages

I need to be able to make an object that is instantiated in a ASP.NET Master Page to be visible to all of the pages in the application that are based on that Master page. At the moment I'm defining the object here:

```
public partial class Control : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public User TheUser;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

... but I think that's where I'm going wrong. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to create a control that inherits from a MasterPage? What you really want to do is create a MasterPage and add a property to it:

```
public partial class MyMasterPage: System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string MyProperty {get;set;}
}
```

Now, from a Page that uses that MasterPage, you can just reference the MasterPage and access its members directly:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyMasterPage m = Master as MyMasterPage;
    string masterProperty = m.MyProperty;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off creating a base page (that inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page`) that all your pages inherit from, add your `TheUser` object to the base page.

Please note, pages do not inherit their master pages.

Comment: There are times when you want to access a MasterPage's members (example  below), but Joe here is probably correct with his assessment. And since you're talking about a "User" object, you might also want to look at ASP.Net Membership.